# Kotlin garbage collect strong referenced lambda

Tags: kotlin

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val printers = Printers()

    private val strongObject = object: Item {
        override fun print(): Int {
            return Log.e("MainActivity", "strongObject")
        }
    }

    private val strongSAM = {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "strongSAM")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val localObject = object: Item {
            override fun print(): Int {
                return Log.e("MainActivity", "localObject")
            }
        }
        val localSAM = {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "localSAM")
        }
        printers.add(strongObject)
        printers.add(strongSAM)
        printers.add(localObject)
        printers.add(localSAM)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content).setOnClickListener {
            printers.dump()
        }
    }

}
```

Item.java:

```
public interface Item {
    int print();
}
```

Printers.java:

```
public class Printers {
    List<WeakReference<Item>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(final Item item) {
        list.add(new WeakReference<>(item));
    }

    public void dump() {
        Log.e("Printers", "Size: " + list.size());
        for (final WeakReference<Item> item: list) {
            if (item.get() != null) {
                item.get().print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Size: 4
strongObject
```

If you run this program you will notice that garbage collector will garbage collect strongSAM, localSAM and localObject. However strongSAM has a strong reference how can it be garbage collected?

I tried to use dex2jar and Luyten to view the generated class file:
[image]

From the class viewer in the generated class the strongSAM is indeed a field and has a strong reference.

Comment: As you can see from the class file, the actual function object for `strongSam` might be not be instantiated before you actually need it to conform to the SAM-type (which is when you call `printers.add(strongSAM)`). The SAM-object might therefore only exist within the scope of the `onCreate` method.

Comment: But even if it is instantiated in onCreate it is assigned to the field strongSAM so it has a strong reference.

Comment: No, it is assigned to the local variable `strongSam` which is shadowing the outer field. See line 7 of the decompiled class file (`MainActivityKt$sam$Item$f92c66a0 strongSam;`).

Comment: Oh you are right it is not assigned. I am curious why it creates a local variable.

Comment: Probably because it can't assign an `Item` to a `Function0<Integer>` variable. The function type could also conform to other SAM-types, so you would need to create them somewhere.

Comment: Also, the outer `strongSam` is final, so it can't be reassigned.